# Talend Open Studio - tMsSqlInput "Guess schema" error

Tags: jdbc, talend

When clicking on the button "Guess schema" on a tMsSqlInput I get the error "Database connection is failed". The details are:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
>   at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:164)

Do you have any idea ?

Configuration : 
I'm using TalendOpenStudio 5.6.1 in 32bits connected to a MSSQL DB SQLServer 2008R2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have the jTDS driver on the classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My computer hasn't been restarted for about a week. In my case, I've restarted, relaunched Talend Open Studio, and it worked ! I didn't know what was the root cause, sorry not to help so much someone that would have the same issue in future.